# getting deadlock while trying to execute findAll() using jpa for MySql database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using JPA (Spring `RepositoryRestResource`) for persistence and the database is Mysql. While I am calling GET API from UI it calls (`WorkflowServiceImpl.getActivities()`) method. It only has `findAll()` method of JPA to get list of data. But I am seeing deadlock issues while making this call.

My question is why its going into deadlock situation when all its doing is fetch and no update statement getting executed? please help me to fix this issue?

**Code to getActivities()**

```
@Override
public Map<String, WorkflowTemplateDTO> getActivities() {
    //adding all activities
    return workflowTemplateRepository.findAll().stream()
            .map(workflowTemplate -> {
                Set<DefinitionType> pageTypes = getAllPagesOfWorkflow(workflowTemplate).stream()
                        .map(PageTemplate::getType)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

                return workflowTemplate.toWorkflowTemlateDTO(pageTypes);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(WorkflowTemplateDTO::getId, Function.identity()));
}


public List<PageTemplate> getAllPagesOfWorkflow(WorkflowTemplate workflowTemplate) {
    return workflowPageRepository.findAllByWorkflowTemplate(workflowTemplate).stream()
            .map(WorkflowPage::getPageTemplate).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/serve_mar
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**Error log**

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:287)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:536)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:534)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:305)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.workflow.services.impl.WorkflowServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f31a06d8.getActivities(<generated>)
        at com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.workflow.controllers.WorkflowController.getWorkflowTemplates(WorkflowController.java:38)
        at com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.workflow.controllers.WorkflowController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c029c43e.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
        at com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.common.controller.ControllerLoggingAspect.profile(ControllerLoggingAspect.java:39)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor185.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.workflow.controllers.WorkflowController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bddfbb1b.getWorkflowTemplates(<generated>)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor225.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.security.config.SessionValidationFilter.doFilter(SessionValidationFilter.java:52)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect$3.convert(MySQLDialect.java:546)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3360)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3233)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3634)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2486)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532)
        ... 114 common frames omitted
    Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:123)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:955)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1094)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1042)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1345)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1027)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
        ... 132 common frames omitted
```

Entity file

```
package com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.page.models;

import com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.common.models.AuditableEntity;
import com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.common.models.DefinitionType;
import com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.common.utils.PageConverter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class PageTemplate extends AuditableEntity {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @Column(length = 1024)
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @Column(columnDefinition = "mediumtext")
    @Convert(converter = PageConverter.class)
    private PageDefinition definition;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 45)
    private DefinitionType type;

    public PageTemplate() {
        // for jackson purpose onlypage
    }

    public PageTemplate(@NotNull String id, @NotNull String title, String description, PageDefinition definition,
            DefinitionType type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.definition = definition;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public DefinitionType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(DefinitionType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public PageDefinition getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }

    public void setDefinition(PageDefinition definition) {
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        PageTemplate that = (PageTemplate) o;
        return Objects.equals(title, that.title) && Objects.equals(description, that.description)
                && Objects.equals(definition, that.definition) && Objects.equals(type, that.type);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(title, description, definition, type);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PageTemplate{" + "id=" + id + ", title='" + title + '\'' + ", description='" + description + '\''
                + ", definition='" + definition + '\'' + ", type='" + type + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

What I observed from logs is that for every `findAll()` or `findById()` call for PageTemplate.java entity class **1 select and 1 update sql are executed by hibernate**. I am not sure why?. This is happening only for this particular entity, and for all others its executing only 1 select statement.

```
2020-04-15 01:43:54,551 INFO com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.common.controller.ControllerLoggingAspect [http-nio-8090-exec-7] received rest call at com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.workflow.controllers.WorkflowController.pageTemplate with arguments [chathours_p0]
Hibernate: select pagetempla0_.id as id1_15_0_, pagetempla0_.created_by as created_2_15_0_, pagetempla0_.created_on as created_3_15_0_, pagetempla0_.last_updated_by as last_upd4_15_0_, pagetempla0_.last_updated_on as last_upd5_15_0_, pagetempla0_.definition as definiti6_15_0_, pagetempla0_.description as descript7_15_0_, pagetempla0_.title as title8_15_0_, pagetempla0_.type as type9_15_0_ from page_template pagetempla0_ where pagetempla0_.id=?
Hibernate: update page_template set last_updated_by=?, last_updated_on=?, definition=?, description=?, title=?, type=? where id=?
2020-04-15 01:43:54,609 INFO com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.common.controller.ControllerLoggingAspect [http-nio-8090-exec-7] rest call at com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.workflow.controllers.WorkflowController.pageTemplate returning response PageTemplate{id=chathours_p0, title='Operational Hours', description='Operational Hours', definition='com.tfsc.ilabs.selfservice.page.models.PageDefinition@1199f9f', type='UPDATE'}, Method execution time 58 milliseconds
```

Any suggestion to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Java stream work on terminal operation like `Collect`, so deadlock happens becasuse of it.
Here `workflowTemplateRepository.findAll()` already not fetched before you use result to query in other data. Avoid call repository inside stream map() to prevent deadlock.

You can try this way to prevent deadlock

```
@Override
public Map<String, WorkflowTemplateDTO> getActivities() {
    //adding all activities
    List<WorkflowTemplate> workflowTemplates = workflowTemplateRepository.findAll();
    Map<String, WorkflowTemplateDTO>  mp = new HashMap<String, WorkflowTemplateDTO>();
    for(WorkflowTemplate workflowTemplates : workflowTemplates) {
         Set<DefinitionType> pageTypes = getAllPagesOfWorkflow(workflowTemplate).stream()
                        .map(PageTemplate::getType)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        WorkflowTemplateDTO workflowTemplateDTO = workflowTemplate.toWorkflowTemlateDTO(pageTypes);
        mp.put(workflowTemplateDTO.getId(),workflowTemplateDTO )
    }
    return workflowTemplates;
}


public List<PageTemplate> getAllPagesOfWorkflow(WorkflowTemplate workflowTemplate) {
    return workflowPageRepository.findAllByWorkflowTemplate(workflowTemplate).stream()
            .map(WorkflowPage::getPageTemplate).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: This is not working, What i observed is that when I call findAll() for one the entity (PageTemplate), hibernate is executing 1 update statement for every select statement. I have updated in description. Any idea why hibernate is executing update when I am doing findById() or findAll().

Comment: @sushil it is not working means ? Again deadlock happened ?

Comment: May be deadlock not happened again, if you have any logical problem then that is not  part of my solution. (Since you don't describe what operation you want to do)

Comment: Deadlock was happening due to update statements getting executed along with findById() method of repositotyRestResource. Earlier I had @ Transactional at class level for Service class, Now I moved @ Transactional to method level only for required methods. And with this Deadlock issue is resolved.

Comment: You don't even post service details how can we know what you are using or not. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

The query triggers a flush of changes that aren't persisted yet. 
You need to identify the changes and see why they cause a deadlock.

Comment: any idea how to identify changes that are not flushed yet? aren't these transactions managed by jpa, API which is failing is called to load Home page elements and till that no transactions were initiated.

Comment: I'd check if you can add/activate logging on your connection to see all sql statements. Also use a debugger to check the 1st level cache in you EntityManager.

BTW: I think Abinash might be right.